# Layouts and reports

Tags: qgis, import, reports

I am working with qgis for 1 year now and start to be familiar with "layouts". I have just discover the "report", and undestood that reports are very useful for automation of complex reports.

I have done what I needed as 4 different layouts (representing 4 different levels of details of a project), I "just have to manually sort and spread" the 4 different reports in a special order of hierarchy of levels). "Reports" seems to be abble to handle this for me.

Is there a way to include/import into sections of a report what I have done as layouts?
Or do I have to recreate the layout design in the sections of the report?

Qgis 3.22.4 on Windows

Comment: No ideas, no answers????

Comment: I want to do the same. How have you solved it?

Comment: Unfortunately no. It seems it is not possible with the current version of Qgis. Report is a good tool but not yet mature, a lot of features has still to be created.  Hope this will come in further versions.

Comment: I' not sure. I guese you got no answer because the question is not clear. Reports and Atlas Tool are very powerful and I think it should bei possible to so what you want.

Comment: By the moment my solution is save the Layout like a template and after that in the report I add elements from template. Obviously if I change the layout, the report doesn’t update.

Comment: Without a detailed description of your use-case, no proper answer, unfortunately... We can't start guessing in the dark what you try to do.

Comment: Sorry I miwed 2 posts that I wrote.

Comment: Sorry I was also refering to another post I did some weeks ago.
This one is just about re-using something developped by the layout functionality into the report feature.
The other  post  can be reached at https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/716133?noredirect=1 in that post i explained what i wanted to do, and never succeeded, even with a very simple example.

Comment: I want to do a 3 level report, first level the roads, second level the stakes along each road, and 3rd level the pannels on each stake. So if I have 2 roads (road1 and road 2), the first road with 1 stake (stake 1) with 3 pannels (pan 1 to 3), the second road with 2 stakes (stake 2 and 3), the first (stake 2) with 2 pannels (pan 4 and 5) and the second (stake 3) with 1 pannel (pan 5)
So what I would like to have is an automatic report that will print the following reports :

road 1 / stake1 / Pan 1/ pan 2 / pan 3 / road 2 / stake 2 / pan 4 / pan 5 / stake 3 /pan 5

Comment: This will greatly help me because the real project has about 100 roads, 250 stakes, 600 pannels...

WIth the simple test I did, it appears that the link between road, stake and pan did not work, so I had (with the exemple given) road1 / stake 1 / all the pans / stake 2 /all the pans again / stake 3 / all the pans/stake 4 /all the pans  ...... and then again the same with road 2. even after reading the tips on that report feature.

Comment: You should edit you initial post and add the additional information there to get enough attention for your question.